# Where are the Grunt plugins?

Tags: gruntjs

I can't find any Grunt plugins on the [Grunt website](https://gruntjs.com/plugins). Where are they? Moreover Grunt isn't working anymore on my computer. When I call

```
npm install
```

I get the error:

> No matching version found for grunt-contrib-copy@>1.0.0

Answer (score 0):

Grunt is a quite old taskrunner by todays standards, while it is still in use in a lot of places the activity on the projects github has been really slow since like 2014-2015.

You can see it for yourself at https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt/graphs/code-frequency.

So if the plugins page has stopped working I would think that something has just failed on their website and no one has noticed yet. The nice thing to do here would be to file an issue on their website repo so [I did that](https://github.com/gruntjs/gruntjs.com/issues/207).

For the other part of your question, [grunt-contrib-copy](https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-contrib-copy) is available via NPM as version 1.0.0 and installs fine for me.

```
$ npm install grunt-contrib-copy

+ grunt-contrib-copy@1.0.0
added 9 packages from 3 contributors and audited 10 packages in 0.616s
found 0 vulnerabilities
```

It hasn't been updated since 2016 so nothing should have changed there. It could have been a temporary outage of the NPM service or maybe you are using an alternative repo of some kind?